# Show size value of element during CSS transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When a user scroll to certain element on my page I add class which starts an animation of the width of it. I starts of with a width of 0% then goes up to 99% for example. As this animates is there a way to display this width incrementing in the page in HTML ie a `<p>` tag with this value incrementing?
The CSS is just this, I add the class .active when the user scrolls to it with Javascript.

```
.graph-horiz-bar__bar{
  background:$niagara;
  top:0px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
.graph-horiz-bar__bar.active{
  width:100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var div = document.getElementById("yourDiv"), parapgraph = document.getElementById("yourParagraph");  
setInterval(function(){
    paragraph.innerHTML = div.offsetWidth + "px";
}, 20);
```

This sets the paragraphs content to the div's width every 20 ms.

Comment: `document.getElementById("yourDiv").width` ??? Also, query the DOM for an element every 20ms is such a terrible idea.

Comment: again... Be careful `Element.width` returns `undefined`...  
Also it would be ultra cool to stop that interval after some time, don't you think? (not to say that would be nice to start it when needed, at least)

Comment: **No, it's not fixed**. It's wrong: `style.width` will return `""`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan now it is.

Comment: :) almost, now it would be useful to suggest that the interval should be triggered from within a function that registers that the element is inViewport, than you should stop the interval using the `transitionend` event. It's easy with jQuery: `$(".graph-horiz-bar__bar").on("transitionend", stopMyInterval)`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Well, you see, I don't use JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to animate the element width using jQuery `.animate()` and reading the current width from the `step:` parameter callback (Read the Docs)...

**Using CSS3 transition:**

```js
var $bar = $("#bar"),
    $currWidth = $("#currWidth"),
    itv = null;

$("#bar").on({
  // START COUNTING THE WIDTH
  // I used a custom "start" event cause currently (2016) 
  // Event.transitionstart is implemented only in IE10+, Edge
  start : function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    itv = setInterval(function(){
      $currWidth.text($bar[0].offsetWidth);
    },10);
  },
  // STOP COUNTING THE WIDTH
  transitionend : function() {
    clearInterval(itv);
    $currWidth.text("INTERVAL STOPPED");
  }
});


$("#start").on("click", function(){ // CLICK JUST FOR DEMO,
  // You need to place this trigger inside your inViewport method
  // when the element enters the viewport
  $bar.trigger("start"); // <<---------------- 
});
```

```css
#bar{
  height: 20px;
  width:0;
  background:red;
  transition: 3s;
}
#bar.active{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">ACTIVATE BAR</button><!-- TRIGGER BUTTON JUST FOR DEMO -->

width <span id="currWidth">0</span>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

---

When `transitionstart` will be implemented by all major browsers than the code would look pretty much like:

```
var itv;

$("#bar").on({
  transitionstart: function(){
    itv = setInterval(function(){
      console.log( $bar[0].offsetWidth );
    },10);
  },
  transitionend : clearInterval(itv)
});

$("#bar").addClass("active"); // place this call where needed
```

Probably some day in another galaxy some event like `transitionstep` could be all it takes....

```
$("#bar").on("transitionstep", function(){ // :( 
   console.log( this.offsetWidth );
});
```